# How do I try ActionMailer receive method in local development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actionmailer

I'm writing an application that will receive emails forwarded by postfix to the rails app in the production server. But, how do I test the `Mailer#receive` method in local development? Do I need to set up postfix locally?